# No Keyboard support while logging in after installing additional drivers for Wacom

Tags: boot, drivers, keyboard, wacom

I installed drivers for the Wacom Babmoo tablet and now I am basically locked out of my laptop, neither keyboard nor mouse are responding (regardless of external or touch pad).

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The problem occurred after installing some xserver package that the wacom tablet driver was dependent on. I cannot figure out how to solve this problem. As of now, I have booted into a Ubuntu Live CD to backup the most recent changes.

I've tried to go into recovery mode and mounting the partition as read/write but whenever I do that the system crashes/hangs.
So how do I recover from here? Can I modify the packages from the live CD? Is there something that I am missing in regards to the recovery mode?

All help is very much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Reboot the machine.
2. Select recovery mode on grub
3. Enable networking
4. Drop to root shell prompt
5. Type `apt install xserver-xorg-input-all`

This should recover mouse, keyboard, AND your wacom as viable Xorg inputs :D

Hope this helps!